# Integrating Neo4j with Laravel 6, Which Driver?

Tags: neo4j, laravel-6

The current version of the `vinelab/neoelpquent` (1.4.7) does not support Laravel 6.  What's the next best alternative?  `graphaware/neo4j-php-client` ?  Presumably I would need to bind this as a singleton into the service container?